# Windows 7 - Open the Volume Control popup from the command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, audio

I would like to open the **Volume Control** popup directly without using the mouse or keyboard. Currently, I am using [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to focus on the system tray, <kbd>Left</kbd> to highlight the Volume Control icon [image: icon], and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the popup.

[image: volume control]

---

I assume that this is possible, considering that you can open the **View Available Networks** window with

```
rundll32 van.dll,RunVAN
```

as opposed to using the Network icon [image: icon].

---

Is there a way to invoke the Volume Control popup from the command prompt? Please note that I am not looking to use the **Volume Mixer** (`sndvol`):

[image: volume mixer]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`sndvol.exe` is what you want, you just need to use the `-f` flag to make it show just the master volume slider:

```
sndvol.exe -f
```

Running just `sndvol.exe` opens the volume mixer, as you noted.

Comment: Future Googlers: Note that you can access Mute button with `Tab Spacebar`

Answer (score 9):

`sndvol.exe` allows you to specify window coordinates after `-f` and `-t` switches:

> coordinates = y * 65536 + x, where x and y are signed integers

This command will open a window at x=500 y=400:

```
sndvol.exe -f 26214900
```

`-f` switch opens Volume Control, `-t` opens Volume Mixer.

Comment: In 2022, on Windows 10 you must use `-t` option for coordinates. For example, to open Volume Mixer as OS does itself by clicking on context menu item (right click on Speaker icon) run this command `sndvol.exe -t 99490633`

Answer (score 7):

### Addendum:

As mentioned in [my comment](https://superuser.com/questions/440751/windows-7-open-the-volume-control-popup-from-the-command-prompt#comment509888_440752), using `sndvol -f` as per **@Indrek**'s answer opens the **Volume Control** window in an unusual location, away from the system tray. Using AutoHotkey, we can make the popup appear where we see fit:

```
SetWinDelay, -1
Run, % "sndvol -f"
WinWaitActive, ahk_class #32770
WinMove, % A_ScreenWidth - 84, % A_ScreenHeight - 305 - 48
```

This script places the window at the bottom right of the screen. You can customize it to by changing the last line (`WinMove`).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

On windows XP:  Use `sndvol32` as follows

`sndvol32` no params to display master volume window

`sndvol32 -x` to display small master volume window

`sndvol32 -t` to display volume control only (as per sound icon)