# Location of sndvol.exe using a flag/arg

Tags: windows-10

I am using a desktop customisation tool to open the Volume Mixer: "sndvol.exe".

I found whilst searching that there is a way to choose where/which monitor it opens on.

Using this "sndvol.exe" -T 75611119 0

Opens it on my #3 of 3 monitors - or more specifically the leftmost.

From what was inferred the -T 75611119 0 flag/arg can determine spcifically where.

-T 75611119 0 places my little app window at the furthest lower left position.

Can -T 75611119 0 <--this be changed? And if so, specifically according to pixels? e.g. 90w x 240h from the furthest left upper corner?

Thanks :)

Comment: value is calculated by `coordinates = y * 65536 + x, where x and y - signed integers` https://superuser.com/questions/440751/windows-7-open-the-volume-control-popup-from-the-command-prompt No idea about multi monitor though

Comment: Thanks Chris C, I have 3 monitors of 1920x1080 or a total of 5760x1080.

Comment: Thanks Chris C, I have 3 monitors of 1920x1080 = 5760x1080. If I make the the value -T o o it goes to the centre monitor's upper left. The formula doesnt seem to understand the huge negative value of -1920 * 65536 + 0