# Windows 10 volume slider trigger location

Tags: windows-10, audio, notifications

I need to create a desktop shortcut for volume slider of windows 10 which is currently triggered by system volume icon located in system tray. Can anyone help me to find the location or create a shortcut for the volume slider.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JNiQK56GOxaoVnl1GG7uM6VHMC4TuuwN/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

- [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=47784) and similar third-party tools can control volume directly.
- Make a "desktop" shortcut to `sndvol.exe` and set its keyboard shortcut. To display just the master volume setting, [use the `-f` command line option](https://superuser.com/questions/440751/windows-7-open-the-volume-control-popup-from-the-command-prompt).

Comment: Although it's worked but it shows old windows 7 style volume slider not the windows 10 volume slider. Can you help me on that...